# Exception when combining Omnifaces and PrimeFaces LazyDataModel on Payara Micro

Tags: jsf, serialization, primefaces, omnifaces, payara-micro

I run into an Exception when adding the OmniFaces maven dependency to an existing working Project:

```
[2016-06-28T17:19:09.280+0200] [Payara Micro 4.1] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-CORE-00037] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=http-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1467127149280] [levelValue: 1000] [[An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.String to field org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel.data of type java.util.List in instance of org.primefaces.showcase.view.data.datatable.LazyCarDataModel
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2083)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1995)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)    
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1155)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1155)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readRemainingObject(StandardSession.java:2079)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1987)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.deserialize(StandardSession.java:1274)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StoreBase.readSession(StoreBase.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.web.ha.session.management.ReplicationStore.getSession(ReplicationStore.java:567)
    at org.glassfish.web.ha.session.management.ReplicationStore.getSession(ReplicationStore.java:519)
    at org.glassfish.web.ha.session.management.ReplicationStore.loadFromBackingStore(ReplicationStore.java:433)
    at org.glassfish.web.ha.session.management.ReplicationStore.load(ReplicationStore.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase.doSwapIn(PersistentManagerBase.java:1215)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase.swapIn(PersistentManagerBase.java:1175)
    at org.glassfish.web.ha.session.management.ReplicationManagerBase.findSession(ReplicationManagerBase.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.isRequestedSessionIdValid(Request.java:2996)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseSessionCookiesId(Request.java:4113)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:354)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
]]
```

I can reproduce the Exception with the PrimeFaces 6.0 Showcase, so it looks like the cause is not within my code.

This is how to reproduce with PrimeFaces showcase:

1. Download [PrimeFaces 6.0 showcase](https://github.com/primefaces/showcase) sources from github.
2. Add an OnmiFaces dependency to `pom.xml`:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
       <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
       <version>2.3</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Add the Maven code for Payara Micro Uber Jar creation from http://blog.payara.fish/creating-uber-jar-with-payara-micro to `pom.xml`
4. Build with `mvn package` and then start with `java -jar showcase-6.0.jar`
5. Now start the showcase on localhost and open the DataTable Lazy Loading example and you should get the exception.

The exeption does not occur, when the OmniFaces dependency is removed. And it does not occur on Payara Application Server, but only on Payara Micro.

So I'm not sure if the error is in OmniFaces, Payara Micro, PrimeFaces or wherever.

Comment: It might be a bug in Payara Micro, if the same works correctly in Payara Server. Do you have multiple instances of Payara Micro running (in cluster), or you are running a single instance?
It is better to raise an issue on [Payara issue tracker](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues).

Comment: Created Payara issue: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/884

Comment: Issue does not arise when starting Payara Micro with the --noCluster option. So if clustering is not required, this is a workaround until issue is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is caused by `<distributable>` flag which was [added](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/96) to OmniFaces 2.1 in order to support running on a cluster.

This has in turn uncovered some bugs in PrimeFaces 6.0, PrimeFaces showcase application and Payara Micro.

- PrimeFaces 6.0 new [`PhaseInfo`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/lifecycle/PhaseInfo.java) class implements `Serializable`, but has a [`PhaseId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseId.html) property which isn't `Serializable` at all.
- In PrimeFaces showcase there are several `Serializable` view scoped beans having a non-serializable service property such as [`CarService`](https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/blob/6_0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/showcase/service/CarService.java) in [`LazyView`](https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/blob/6_0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/showcase/view/data/datatable/LazyView.java) backing bean behind the lazy data table demo page.
- Payara Micro seems to not consider WAR's own `web.xml` whether it has `<distributable>` flag set. If this flag is not set, then the container should not assume the WAR as distributable.

The very same serialization problems with PrimeFaces 6.0 and PrimeFaces showcase are reproducible when you remove OmniFaces altogether, but set the `<distributable>` flag in `web.xml` of PrimeFaces showcase. Each of those issues need to reported individually. I have at least reported the `PhaseInfo` matter as [issue 1570](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1570) and posted a [comment](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/884#issuecomment-230092130) on your Payara Micro issue.

On a slightly related note, I also noticed that PrimeFaces showcase's `web.xml` has set Mojarra-specific  `com.sun.faces.serializeServerState` to `false`. I have not investigated the effects when set back to `true`, but this setting of `false` is **not** recommended as it may hide other bugs related to view building and state management.

Comment: You can run Payara Micro with --noCluster then it won't consider the application for clustering. By default Payara Micro runs clustered so will attempt to deploy all applications as clustered.

Comment: @leetjava: that was indeed commented in the issue and even on the question :)